# how to download images from a cross origin url that has no cors

Tags: html, reactjs

So I have a array of image URLs from a website that does not have cors, I want the user to be able to click a button and it will download all the images, but CORS does not allow that. So I am scratching my head right now

Comment: You need a server proxy

Comment: could u explain more?